# Beamer Progress Dots Not Aligned

Tags: beamer

I'm using Beamer for a presentation with progress bars. I've used the main.tex of this presentation for a few other presentations without any problems, now I've copied it to create a new presentation but the progress dots are misaligned and not side by side. How can I correct this?

[image: the problematic progress dots]

The relevant part of Beamer is as follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
% Theme choice:
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% Title page details: 
\title{First results of Rear-Wall Final-State Distribution calculations}%{Theoretical Studies Related to the Rear-Wall Final-State Distribution} %What should be the title? 
\author[]{}
\institute[ ]{\inst{1} 
\and
\inst{2} 
 \and 
\inst{3} 
\and
\inst{4}}

\logo{\large \LaTeX{}}

\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/katrin.png}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/logo_amo.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{figures/icl.jpg}%
}

\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

\setframeofframes{/}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Please don't just post your preamble, always make a compilable minimal working example which actually reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are missing the `compress` option to get them side-by-side
- you don't need to load xcolor, amsmath or graphicx, beamer loads them for you
- I wouldn't use the `multicol` package with beamer, beamer has its own column mechanism

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
% Theme choice:
\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% Title page details: 
\title{First results of Rear-Wall Final-State Distribution calculations}%{Theoretical Studies Related to the Rear-Wall Final-State Distribution} %What should be the title? 
\author[]{}
\institute[ ]{\inst{1} 
\and
\inst{2} 
 \and 
\inst{3} 
\and
\inst{4}}

\logo{\large \LaTeX{}}

\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}%
}

\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

\setframeofframes{/}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]